# Stored procedure in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I'm trying to do a very simple stored procedure for a class project. I just want to use it to execute a simple insert statement.

What I have is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insertSpa (p_spaID IN INTEGER, s_sdate IN VARCHAR2, p_address IN VARCHAR2)
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO spa( spaID,sdate,address)
VALUES (p_spaid, p_sdate, p_address);
END;
/
```

And then to call it, I've been using:

```
exec insertSpa( p_spaID => 9999, p_sDate => '12122012', p_address => '1234 Main St. 12345' );
```

When I try and run the first portion, I get an error that says "Procedure created with compilation errors." Here is what the spa relation is:

```
SPAID : NOT NULL NUMBER(38)
SDATE : VARCHAR2(8)
ADDRESS : VARCHAR2(100)
```

Comment: That is T-SQL for Microsoft SQL Server, not PL/SQL for Oracle. You should really read the Oracle (PL/SQL) manual before doing anything else

Comment: You can use the same name for variables in PL/SQL as for columns in SQL statements if you namespace the variables with the procedure name when you use them in SQL. That way you won't have that ugly p_ prefix on every variable. You'd just use: "... values (insertSpa.spaid, insertSpa.sdate, insertSpa.address);"

Comment: When you get compilation errors, you can type "show errors" to display the errors.

Comment: So whatever you name the variables after the procedure name, that is what they have to be referred to in the procedure as well as when you use the exec command? And I take it if you used the same name as what they are in the actual table, then there is conflicts there?

Similar to functions in C/C++?

Comment: @JustinCave Thanks for that. I was wondering why it wouldn't show them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, from what you've shown, the procedure compiles OK, and it's the `exec` - which is just shorthand for an anonymous block - that says there is an error. It would have been helpful if you'd shown the error stack. (If the procedure, or any named blocked, said it had a compilation error, you could get the details with `show errors`, or by selecting from the `user_errors` view).

You created your procedure with the second parameter named `s_sdate`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insertSpa (p_spaID IN INTEGER,
  s_sdate IN VARCHAR2, p_address IN VARCHAR2)
```

... but when you call it you're saying the name is `p_sDate`:

```
exec insertSpa( p_spaID => 9999, p_sDate => '12122012', ...
```

The names have to match. Given the other names, presumably the procedure declaration should change to `p_sDate`. Actually, you have a mismatch between the procedure declaration and where you're using it in the procedure, so you'd get both errors - on compile and on `exec` - so you should definitely change it in the declaration. I missed that you'd said you had a procedure compilation, somehow.

Comment: Ah. There we go. I also had the variable named wrong in the input line. Thank you for catching the typo. Everything works now.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that, among other things, you are trying to use SQL Server's T-SQL syntax in Oracle rather than PL/SQL.  I'm guessing that `spaid` is intended to be an integer, `sdate` is intended to be an integer (though since it appears to represent a `date`, it really ought to be defined as a date), and `address` is intended to be a string.  I'm also guessing that the `spa` table has three columns `spaID`, `sDate`, and `address`.  If those guesses are accurate, something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insertSpa( p_spaID IN INTEGER,
                                       p_sdate IN INTEGER,
                                       p_address IN VARCHAR2 )
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO spa( spaID, sDate, address )
    VALUES( p_spaID, p_sdate, p_address );
END;
```

should compile.  You would then call it

```
SQL> exec insertSpa( p_spaID => 9999, - 
                     p_sDate => 12122012, - 
                     p_address => '1234 Main St. 12345' );
```

The error that you are getting seems to imply that you never created the stored procedure.  Did you actually run the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement?  It sounds like maybe you just created the script on your local client machine but then never executed it to create the procedure.  You can run the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement directly in SQL*Plus.  Or you can save it to a file and execute the script in SQL*Plus

```
SQL> @<<name of .sql script>>
```

Comment: It still isn't working. What do I have to do to compile the SP? I just have it saved as a .sql file. I'm not working

Comment: @Seldom - Define "not working".  Are you getting an error?  If so, post the error.  Are you getting an error when you run the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement?  Or when you execute the procedure?  Are my guesses about the column names and data types correct?  If not, posting the definition of the `spa` table would be helpful.  Cutting and pasting from the SQL*Plus session to show us exactly what you are doing and seeing is also very helpful.

Comment: Yes, all the assumptions you made were correct. The errors I'm getting are:

Comment: @Seldom - Please edit your question to post additional information.  Please don't put that in comments.

Comment: Remember that `exec` can't be split across multiple lines, unless [you use the hyphen continuation character](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve022.htm) *8-)

Comment: @AlexPoole - Good point.  I added multiple lines to avoid scrolling and forgot about that complication.

Comment: When I wrote it in code, I just did it all as one line, and it still wasn't working, giving the errors in the original question.

Comment: @Seldom - As I asked in my answer, did you actually run the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement?

Comment: I didn't see that part of your updated answer. I never did that. I guess it seems obvious now that I know that. I'll try that and hopefully it works.

Comment: I tried to execute the file that it is stored in with @<name> and it just opens up the editor. Is there a semicolon or some other thing missing?

Comment: @Seldom - Are you saying that in SQL*Plus, you type `@<<name of .sql file>>` and that opens up the file in whatever text editor you have configured SQL*Plus to call out to?  I can't imagine why or how that would happen.  Or, perhaps, are you saying that it merely displays the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement in SQL*Plus and is waiting for you to enter the `/` character to execute the current buffer?

Comment: I guess it was waiting for the / character. When I've run other commands using @<name> they just execute. Is there a way to make it so it just runs?

Comment: @Seldom - You can add the `/` character on a new line at the end of the `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE` statement in the .sql file.

Comment: Ok, so I got the correct syntax for compilation, but now it's saying that I'm getting compilation errors and so when I try and exec it's not finding the SP. Updating original question with what I have.